# Read pandas dataframe row by row, call API and then store each result in a separate pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Currently I am stuck in a problem. I hope I will get some solution here. I have a python dataframe with 100000 rows and 10 columns. Now I want to iterate over pandas dataframe row by row and pass it through API. after calling API, i want to store the incoming result as a separate pandas dataframe and write to a table. Please let me know if it is possible, If yes, then any sample piece of code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling row by API call, and want to add that row in another data frame, here's code for that.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(result)
```

Note that the result here is the output of your API call.
This code will append every row you'll get after API call.
Then after, you can convert the dataframe to your [choice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id12/)